# Weyl transformation of Ricci tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, conformal-field-theory

We define the Weyl transform as,
$$
\tilde{g}_{\mu\nu}=\Omega^2g_{\mu\nu},
$$
wherein $\Omega^2$ is a scalar function of space-time $x$.

The Weyl transformed Christoffel symbol can be obtained by inserting the above relation, e.g.,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\tilde{\Gamma}^\lambda_{\mu\nu}
&=\frac{1}{2}\tilde{g}^{\lambda\gamma}\left\{\partial_\mu\tilde{g}_{\gamma\nu}+\partial_v\tilde{g}_{\gamma\mu}-\partial_\gamma\tilde{g}_{\mu\nu}\right\}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\Omega^{-2}g^{\lambda\gamma}\left\{\partial_\mu(\Omega^2g_{\gamma\nu})+\partial_v(\Omega^2g_{\gamma\mu})-\partial_\gamma(\Omega^2g_{\mu\nu})\right\},
\end{aligned}
$$
and applying the product rule for the partial derivatives. After some simplification we arrive at,
$$
\tilde{\Gamma}^\lambda_{\mu\nu}
=\Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\nu}+\delta^\lambda_\nu(\ln\Omega)_{;\mu}+\delta^\lambda_\mu(\ln\Omega)_{;\nu}-g_{\mu\nu}(\ln\Omega)^{;\lambda}
=:\Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\nu}+A^\lambda_{\mu\nu},
$$
wherein $;\mu$ is our shorthand for the derivative.

In order to find out how the Ricci tensor transforms we again insert our transformed Christoffel connection into the definition of the Ricci tensor, e.g.,
$$
\tilde{R}_{\mu\nu}=\tilde{R}^\rho_{\mu\rho\nu}=\partial_\rho\tilde{\Gamma}^\rho_{\mu\nu}-\partial_\nu\tilde{\Gamma}^\rho_{\rho\mu}+\tilde{\Gamma}^\rho_{\rho\lambda}\tilde{\Gamma}^\lambda_{\mu\nu}-\tilde{\Gamma}^\rho_{\nu\lambda}\tilde{\Gamma}^\lambda_{\rho\mu}.
$$

If we proceed from here we will find mixed terms, for instance, $\Gamma^\rho_{\nu\lambda}A^\lambda_{\rho\mu}$, which **I do not know how to simplify**.
If we expand the term,
$$
\Gamma^\rho_{\nu\lambda}A^\lambda_{\rho\mu}
=\frac{1}{2}g^{\rho\gamma}\left\{\partial_\nu g_{\gamma\lambda}+\partial_\lambda g_{\gamma\nu}-\partial_\gamma g_{\nu\lambda}\right\}\left\{\delta^\lambda_\mu(\ln\Omega)_{;\rho}+\delta^\lambda_\rho(\ln\Omega)_{;\mu}-g_{\rho\mu}(\ln\Omega)^{;\lambda}\right\},
$$
we cannot really do much because the partial derivative of the metric has to be evaluated.

**How does one simplify the mixed terms?**

Edit1:

I know that the result should read,
$$
\tilde{R}_{\mu\nu}=R_{\mu\nu}-(n-2)(\ln\Omega)_{;\mu;\nu}-g_{\mu\nu}(\ln\Omega)_{;\rho}^{;\rho}+(n-2)(\ln\Omega)_{;\mu}(\ln\Omega)_{;\nu}-(n-2)g_{\mu\nu}(\ln\Omega)_{;\rho}(\ln\Omega)^{;\rho}
$$

Comment: the metric is covariantly constant in each of the two frames

Comment: @Wakabaloola how does this help me simplify?

Comment: It's a matter of crunching through the long calculation, and you can make your life easier by breaking it down into smaller easier chunks. E.g., think about which terms are quadratic in $\ln\Omega$, which are linear, and since these are independent structures they will simplify independently. Also, understand how $n$ will appear (it can only appear from terms of the form $g_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\nu}=n$) and focus on all terms proportional to $n$. A subtlety is that $A_{;\mu}$ actually denotes a *covariant* derivative in the final formula. (People usually write $A_{,\mu}$ for partial derivative.)

Comment: @Wakabaloola I agree on your approach for these types of calculations and I believe I have followed these guidelines for this specific problem. That said, I am still stuck at the problem stated in the question that I don't know how to further simplify $\Gamma^\rho_{\nu\lambda}A^\lambda_{\rho\mu}$

Comment: The $\Gamma A$ terms cancel, they don't simplify